# Anyone know how I can do an "if" in rails?

Tags: ruby

I have been working on a small app and at some point while creating a new posting I wanted my app to check the database for certain text value, specifically looking for "completed".

So far I came up with this;

```
@job = current_user.Jobs.where(:all, :project_status => "completed")
if @job.exists?
   do something
else
   send an error
end
```

that was completely wrong, after reading up a little on it and going through few examples I think the following does the same thing;

```
@job = current_user.Jobs.exists?(:conditions = {:project_status => "completed"})
```

but I haven't found an example in my research where the above line goes into "if" condition, do I just do;

```
@job = current_user.Jobs.exists?(:conditions = {:project_status => "completed"})
     if @job
        do something here
     else
        do something else here
     end
```

would that be shorter, cleaner and correct?

Comment: Define "no success"; an `if` is an `if`. What's `has`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if @job.project_status.include?("completed")
 #something here 
else
 #nothing
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if what else the column has in it. Include might not be as fast as evaluating the string.

```
if @job.project_status == 'completed'
 #something here 
end
```

This might end up being faster than include? You also don't need to have an else if nothing will happen.